# Consuming JSON byte array along with application/x-www-form-urlencoded in webservice

Tags: java, web-services, http-post, jax-rs, postman

There are 3 questions. I am using Java Restful webservices and request is HTTP POST

1. how can client send JSON data along with MediaType of application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
   Is it somehow possible using byte array ?
2. How can I consume the JSON data which is sent in byte[] format at server side along with MediaType of application/x-www-form-urlencoded?
3. Can I send JSON in byte array format using Postman client ?

Answer (score 1):

1. (1) Postman will automatically url-encode the JSON. Just enter a key and value is the JSON. (2) Yes, but you will want to Base64 encode the byte array first. See [Java 8's `Base64.Encoder.encodeToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-). If you're not using Java 8, you'll probably want to get an external library.
2. (1) If you just send the url-endoded JSON, and you want to POJOify the JSON, then you should work with a library like Jackson. You could do something like

   ```
   @Path("/encoded")
   public class EncodedResource {
       @POST
       @Path("/json")
       @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
       public Response getResponse(@FormParam("json") String json) 
                                                 throws Exception {
           ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
           Hello hello = mapper.readValue(json, Hello.class);
           return Response.ok(hello.hello).build();
       }

       public static class Hello {
           public String hello;
       } 
   }
   ```

   I've tested this with Postman, typing `json` into the key and `{"hello":"world"}` into the value, and it works fine. The reponse is `world`

   (2) If you are going to Base64 encode it, then you need to do something like

   ```
   @POST
   @Path("/base64")
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
   public Response getResponse(@FormParam("base64") String base64) 
                                                 throws Exception {
       String decoded = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64));
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       Hello hello = mapper.readValue(decoded, Hello.class);
       return Response.ok(hello.hello).build();
   }

   public static class Hello {
       public String hello;
   }
   ```

   I've tested this also with Postman, and it works fine. I used this code

   ```
   String json = "{\"hello\":\"world\"}";
   String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(json.getBytes());
   ```

   to get an encode string (which is `eyJoZWxsbyI6IndvcmxkIn0=`), put that as the value and `base64` as the key. With a request to the method above, I get the same `world` result.
3. I think this should be covered above.